# What's the purpose of the TV room in Old Prehevil in Fear and Hunger 2?

Tags: fear-and-hunger-2

In the house with the rifleman and villager sitting at the table, there's a side room with a TV in it.

[image: TV Room]

In addition to being one of the only (if not only) rooms to have a dynamic popup stating what it is, various characters remark about there being something important about the room in their party chats:

> Karin: "My journalist senses are tingling. There's something very off about this room."
>
> Abella: "Do you notice it? The floor is slightly slanted towards the TV. How odd..."
>
> Olivia: "I've never noticed it before, but you can see yourself pretty well from the dark screen of the television. It's almost like a mirror."
>
> Marcoh: "What are you all looking at? Oh? The television? ... But it's not even on...?"

This reeks of a puzzle or something, but two full playthroughs later I haven't figured out anything to do with it. Is this a puzzle or a reference or something?